# File Deleted from MediaStore but not deleted from Storage

Tags: android-studio, local-storage, mediastore

I'm creating a Music Player. I know that in Api 29 and above , we should Send Request to User for deleting Music file in MediaStore.
and this is where result get back in Api 29 and above:

```
 intentSenderRequest = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                    getActivity().getApplication().getContentResolver().delete(deleteUri, null, null);

                }
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), deleteAudioModel.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                File file = new File(deleteAudioModel.getData());
                file.delete();

                adapter.itemDeleted(itemForDelete);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Not Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

but the music just delete from MediaStore and remain in device storage.
I tried to delete it after User permission by MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA and File.delete method,
but I've got no result.

is there any way for delete file in Api 29 and above?

Comment: Use the contentResolver to delete maybe

Comment: I use it but no result @gtxtreme